# How to get Gallery ID dynamically from page in Nextgen Gallery Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

i want to get the gallery id attached to a post/page in my custom template php file from nextgen gallery wordpress. i have the code so far to pull gallery images from nextgen gallery database.

```
<div id="ngg_lightbox">
<?php 
global $nggdb;
$gallery = $nggdb->get_gallery(14, 'sortorder', 'ASC', true, 0, 0);
foreach($gallery as $image) {
?>    
    <a
    class="shutterset_2413"
    href="<?php echo $image->imageURL; ?>">
    </a>

<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

in the above works which works i have specified the gallery id manually, i want to get the gallery id attached to the specific page via shortcode. can please anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can't you do something like this ? `<?php echo do_shortcode('[normal nextgen gallery shortcode goes here]'); ?>`

Comment: No. im using the custom markup, so i cannot use the shortcode.